# Updating a function variable of a Class in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following class definition in Scala:

```
class Test(A:Set[Any],f:Any => Any){
  var _A:Set[Any]=A
  var _f:Any => Any =f

  def add (a:Any){
    _A = _A + a
    _f = ???
  }
}
```

In the method `add` I can update _A to be _A + a (i.e., adding the element `a` to `_A`). I would like to update function `_f`, such that `_f(a)` returns `a`.

Comment: Saying `_f(a)` returns `a` means given any input return the exact same input? If that is what you meant then the function `identity` in Scala is the  function you are looking for.

Comment: @Akos, I am looking for a general solution of updating function variables in Scala. By this example, I just tried to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you create `Test`. But in this case the code may look like this:

```
_f = (input: Any) => { input /* Or whatever you want to do with this function */ }
```

Or like this:

```
def someFunction(input: Any): Any = input
// ....
_f = someFunction _
```

Comment: I think the complete code for the first approach would be "_f = (input: Any) => { if (input==a) _f else input  }". wouldn't it?

Comment: Well doing `if(input==a) _f` is not enough, because the return type needs to be `Any` so you have to call `_f(input)`. If you want `_f` then you need to change the if structure.

Comment: I correct myself: "_f = (input: Any) => { if (input!=a) _f(input) else input }" will  give me what I want: for the values other than a, it uses old _f and for the values equal to a it returns input. Right?

Comment: This causes a infinite recursive calls for some inputs. For more info look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808805/accessing-the-previous-behaviour-of-a-function-in-a-function-variable-update-in/30808873#30808873].