# Accessing the previous behaviour of a function in a function-type variable update in Scala

Tags: scala

suppose I defined a function variable as bellow in Scala:

```
var _f = (input:Any) => {0}
println(_f('a')); 
println(_f('b'));
```

This works fine and returns me two zeros. I continue to update _f as bellow:

```
_f= (input: Any) => { if (input!='c') _f(input) else 5  }

println(_f('a'));
```

An I am expecting to get zero again **(see the question update part at the end of question)**, but I do not! Instead, I come to the following  error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Character.charValue(Character.java:4398)
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.equalsCharObject(BoxesRunTime.java:177)
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.equals2(BoxesRunTime.java:135)
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.equals(BoxesRunTime.java:125) ....
```

Note that if If call `println(_f('c'))` in place of `println(_f('a'))` second call in the above, I would get 5.

**My Questions:**

> 1) Why this happens? This is answered (see update section)
>
> 2) How can I achieve above intended behaviour (i.e., updating a function variable to return a special value for some inputs, while not touching its behaviour for other inputs)?

---

**Update:**

@plinth answer reveals that in the above, by writing `_f(input)` I recursively call `_f` that causes infinite calls. But in fact, by `_f(input)` I mistakenly intended to achieve the previous behaviour of `_f` function (not a recursive call of it). So the question changes to: **How can I access the previous behaviour of a function in a function variable update?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
_f= (input: Any) => { if (input!='c') _f(input) else 5  }
```

If the the input is not 'c', you call _f again with the same input. That's an infinite non-tail recursive call, so your stack will totally explode.

If your goal is to create an adapter onto an existing function, maybe you want something like this:

```
def wrapper(f: Any => Int)(input:Any) : Int =
{
   if (input != 'c') f(input)
   else 5
}
```

then you can do:

```
var _f = (input:Any) => { 0 }
_f = wrapper(_f)
val x = _f('a') // x = 0
val y = _f('c') // y = 5
```

What this does is return a new function based on the old function by using a partial application of wrapper which will bind the old function into a new one that uses it.

Comment: You are right, but how can I access _f's previous behaviour inside `{ if (input!='c') _f(input) else 5  }` then. In fact, by this code I intend to update _f behaviour for just one input, and leave it as before for the rest.